# Modern way to repeat consistent sections of web pages

Tags: html, xhtml

Currently I'm using a dwt file with Expression Web to reproduce menus & footers across many pages.  However, I realized that I really don't need Expression Web other than for this feature.  I'm currently aware of some other options, but they have drawbacks:
1. server side includes or PHP includes - but these place constraints on file extensions (want to keep html extension)
2. ASP.NET master pages - but don't want an ASP.NET site

Is there another option I've missed?

Comment: Yes, there are **many** options. Search for "HTML templating."

Comment: I searched on that, but don't see any real general solutions, other than JavaScript - I don't want that either since some will have this turned off.

Comment: Okay, so that just means you're looking for server-side options. There are lots of choices, but it all depends on what you're running (or want to run) on the server. You also seem to believe that using PHP forces your URLs to end with `.php`, but this is simply not true.

Comment: Ok - I had bad information about the extensions then - PHP seems to be the winner so far - I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, the majority of the information I get on this topic seems to indeed suggest that either the web page extension has to be .php, or a handler has to be added to have all .html pages parsed for PHP.  This is definitely not an option.

Comment: Your problem is server side. Resolved with a little bit of logic with any language like PHP or others, and/or templates tools like smarty (Google it). To see your pages as html, add some URL Rewriting (Google it).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I've decided that I like the way the dwt file works - nothing needs to be resolved when the page is served, but I don't like the dependence on Expression Web (or DreamWeaver), so I'm going to spend a few hours and make my own utility to handle the dwt logic (e.g., propagate the changes to the appropriate files at design time).